# Automatically select tab from current day

Tags: javascript

I query a provider's API to get the broadcast schedule for the week. I make the individual days selectable via different tabs. This works very well.
However, I am having trouble automatically selecting the current day if no day of the week has been manually selected yet.

What do I need to do to make the current day of the week automatically selected if no tab has been clicked yet?

Here is my fiddle with the code currently used: https://jsfiddle.net/4sd7otwq

```js
function openDAY(evt, DAYName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(DAYName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

var show_schedule = function(schedule){
  var no_entry = 'Leider keine Sendung';
  var days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
  var days_buffer = {mon: [], tue: [], wed: [], thu: [], fri: [], sat: [], sun: []}; 
  Array.prototype.slice.call(schedule).forEach(function(schedule_entry) {
    var start_time = schedule_entry.hour;
    if (start_time < 10) { start_time = '0' + start_time }
    start_time = start_time + ':00 Uhr';
    days_buffer[schedule_entry.day].push('<span style="display: flex; padding-bottom:8px;">' + start_time + ' - ' + schedule_entry.name + '</span>');
  });
  Array.prototype.slice.call(days).forEach(function(schedule_days) {
    if (document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days) !== null) {
      if (days_buffer[schedule_days].length >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days).innerHTML = days_buffer[schedule_days].join('');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days).innerHTML = no_entry;
      }
    }
  }); 
};
laut.fm.station('80er-90er').schedule(show_schedule);
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Broadcast schedule</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.laut.fm/js_tools/lautfm_js_tools.0.10.0.js.min.js" ></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Monday')">Monday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Tuesday')">Tuesday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Wednesday')">Wednesday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Thursday')">Thursday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Friday')">Friday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Saturday')">Saturday</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Sunday')">Sunday</button>
    
</div>

<div id="Monday" class="tabcontent">
  <div id="api_lfm_schedule_mon">Loading...</div>
</div>

<div id="Tuesday" class="tabcontent">
 <div id="api_lfm_schedule_tue">Loading...</div> 
</div>

<div id="Wednesday" class="tabcontent">
  <div id="api_lfm_schedule_wed">Loading...</div>
</div>
<div id="Thursday" class="tabcontent">
 <div id="api_lfm_schedule_thu">Loading...</div>
</div>

<div id="Friday" class="tabcontent">
<div id="api_lfm_schedule_fri">Loading...</div>
</div>

<div id="Saturday" class="tabcontent">
  <div id="api_lfm_schedule_sat">Loading...</div>
</div>
    <div id="Sunday" class="tabcontent">
<div id="api_lfm_schedule_sun">Loading...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that easy the way your code works right now. Having *inline event handlers* (`onclick="..."`) almost always makes things more complicated. This is the case here too.

Instead, you can store the tabs and tab-links in arrays, and use loops to set the attributes and add the events to them.

With that done, you can easily call `openDAY` when the application starts to set the current day of the week.

You can get the day of the week by:

```
new Date().getDay()
```

But this will treat Sunday as the first day of the week, so we do some math with it to make it the last.

```js
var tablinks = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"));
var tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("api_lfm_schedule"));
var tabcontent = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent"));
  
function openDAY(day) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].className = tabcontent[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  tabcontent[day].className += " active";
  tablinks[day].className += " active";
}

tablinks.forEach(function (tablink, day) {
  tablink.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openDAY(day)
  })
})

openDAY((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1)

var show_schedule = function(schedule){
  var no_entry = 'Leider keine Sendung';
  var days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
  var days_buffer = {mon: [], tue: [], wed: [], thu: [], fri: [], sat: [], sun: []}; 
  Array.prototype.slice.call(schedule).forEach(function(schedule_entry) {
    var start_time = schedule_entry.hour;
    if (start_time < 10) { start_time = '0' + start_time }
    start_time = start_time + ':00 Uhr';
    days_buffer[schedule_entry.day].push('<span style="display: flex; padding-bottom:8px;">' + start_time + ' - ' + schedule_entry.name + '</span>');
  });
  Array.prototype.slice.call(tabs).forEach(function(tab, index) {
    if (days_buffer[days[index]].length >= 1) {
      tab.innerHTML = days_buffer[days[index]].join('');
    } else {
      tab.innerHTML = no_entry;
    }
  }); 
};
laut.fm.station('80er-90er').schedule(show_schedule);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Broadcast schedule</h2>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.laut.fm/js_tools/lautfm_js_tools.0.10.0.js.min.js"></script>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks">Monday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Tuesday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Wednesday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Thursday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Friday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Saturday</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Sunday</button>

  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="api_lfm_schedule">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay#using_getday).

```js
function openDAY(evt, DAYName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(DAYName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

var show_schedule = function(schedule){
  var no_entry = 'Leider keine Sendung';
  var days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
  var days_buffer = {mon: [], tue: [], wed: [], thu: [], fri: [], sat: [], sun: []}; 
  Array.prototype.slice.call(schedule).forEach(function(schedule_entry) {
    var start_time = schedule_entry.hour;
    if (start_time < 10) { start_time = '0' + start_time }
    start_time = start_time + ':00 Uhr';
    days_buffer[schedule_entry.day].push('<span style="display: flex; padding-bottom:8px;">' + start_time + ' - ' + schedule_entry.name + '</span>');
  });
  Array.prototype.slice.call(days).forEach(function(schedule_days) {
    if (document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days) !== null) {
      if (days_buffer[schedule_days].length >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days).innerHTML = days_buffer[schedule_days].join('');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('api_lfm_schedule_' + schedule_days).innerHTML = no_entry;
      }
    }
  }); 
};


laut.fm.station('80er-90er').schedule(show_schedule);

const options = { weekday: 'long'};
const currentDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(new Date());

const tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  if(tablinks[i].textContent === currentDay) {
    tablinks[i].classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Broadcast schedule</h2>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//api.laut.fm/js_tools/lautfm_js_tools.0.10.0.js.min.js"></script>
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Monday')">Monday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Tuesday')">Tuesday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Wednesday')">Wednesday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Thursday')">Thursday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Friday')">Friday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Saturday')">Saturday</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openDAY(event, 'Sunday')">Sunday</button>

  </div>

  <div id="Monday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_mon">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="Tuesday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_tue">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="Wednesday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_wed">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Thursday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_thu">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="Friday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_fri">Loading...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="Saturday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_sat">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="Sunday" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="api_lfm_schedule_sun">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```